# Not return anything if the condition fails SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables

```
guid   | id   |   Name
-------+------+----------
1      | 123  |  John
2      |  456 |  Mac
3      |  789 |  Paul
```

The other table is

```
id.   |  modified date    
------+----------------
1     |   26-08-2017
1     |   27-08-2017
1     |   01-09-2017
1     |   02-09-2017
2     |   26-08-2017
2     |   01-09-2017
2     |   02-09-2017
3     |   01-09-2017
3     |   02-09-2017
3     |   03-09-2017
```

Every time the name in the first  table changes for each id it also modifies date in second  table. Like for id 1 name was changed 4 times.

I want all those ids by joining both the tables which was first modified after `01-09-2017`. If the id have even one value before 1st September that should not come under.

According to our tables only id 3 passes the condition since ids 1 and 2 were modified before 1st September (id 1 has 2 values and id 2 has 1 value before 1st September in table two so both fail).

Any help?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: microsoft sql server.....

Comment: What is your expected output? Not sure about the logic for the id. `I want all those id` there is only one for each guid nothing save the old ids

Comment: i mean to say select only those ids which was first modified after 01-09-2017.If the id have even one modified date  before 1st september that should not come under.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
     t1.*, t2.*
FROM 
     table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON 
     t1.guid = t2.id
GROUP BY 
     t1.guid
HAVING MIN(t2.modifieddate ) > '01-09-2017'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.